# QScrollArea with multiple QWidgets only shows empty box

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am trying to create a widget that would display some information. Each information would be a QWidget that contains multiple QLabel with text (the information). My idea is to put multiple (array of these) into a QScrollArea so that the user can view them scrolling up and down. The following code:

```
InfoWidget::InfoWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent){
    widgets = new QVector<MarkerInfoWidget*>();
    csv_data = 0;
    csv_velocity = 0;
    labels = 0;
    infoWidgetLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    setLayout(infoWidgetLayout);
    scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
    scrollWidgetLayout = new QVBoxLayout(scrollArea);
    scrollArea->setLayout(scrollWidgetLayout);
    infoWidgetLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);
    //Test
    QString name = "TEST";
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        MarkerInfoWidget* markerWidget = new MarkerInfoWidget(name, scrollArea);
        scrollWidgetLayout->addWidget(markerWidget);
        widgets->append(markerWidget);
    }
}
```

Both MarkerInfoWidget and InfoWidget extends QWidget. What I am getting is simply a box that has very small text:

[image: small Text Example]

If I drag it out and re-size it, it display correctly:

[image: Re-sized example]

What I have noticed is that if I re-size it too small, it does not generate scrolls. What do I need to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess changing:

```
scrollArea->setLayout(scrollWidgetLayout);
```

to sth like:

```
QFrame* frame = new QFrame(scrollArea);
frame->setLayout(scrollWidgetLayout);
scrollArea->setWidget(frame);
```

As far as i know you have to put widget into QScrollableArea to make it really scrollable. Setting its layout is probably not the thing you want to do.